# Check if a List is a value in a HashMap

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I want to check if a value exists.

My Code:

```
public static final Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<>();

if(m.containsValue("gummi")) {...}
```

My problem is that the value is a List.
How can I check for the List?

Comment: Any update on this? This is a pretty interesting problem to solve. Tunaki is taking a shortcut by assuming caller of the method knows the items in the list and that defeats the purpose. the questioner is asking something entirely different.

Comment: @HorseVoice What would you say that the OP is asking, exactly? It's still not clear to me. Are they asking if any `List` in the `Map` contains `"gummi"`, or are they asking if there exists a `List` in the `Map` that **only** contains `"gummi"`? I'd be happy to write an answer that caters to both situations.

Comment: I guess the former; does any list contain "gummi"?

Comment: @HorseVoice - Here's a Java 7 version (as requested): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925049/check-if-a-list-is-a-value-in-a-hashmap/58873708#58873708

Comment: The question in itself is unclear. To check if the value exists, one would want to check for a similar type. As close as it could be interpreted based on the answers, it should read *if an object exists in any of the values of the `Map`...*

Comment: Just a question. If you need to find if one or more of the lists has element which is "gummi"  do you need this list(s) to work with? I am asking because If you need them then optimal solution is very different from what you are asking for.

Answer (score 15):

So I am going to interpret the question, as wanting to tell whether any value of the `Map` contains the target `String`.

There's probably a more appropriate third-party bi-direction multimap implementation. If you are reading this in the future such a type may be in Java SE - please edit this answer.

Given the data structures, this is going to require searching through the entire data. It may be better to have `Map` mapping the other way. Let's ignore that.

The streams one-liner expression solution:

```
m.values().stream().anyMatch(list -> list.contains("gummi"))
```

**Edit:** For Horse Voice, a non-stream version.

```
flatContains(m.values(), "gummi")
```

where

```
public static boolean flatContains(
    Iterable<? extends Collection<?>> collections,
    Object value
) {
    for (Collection<?> collection : collections) {
        if (collection.contains(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Often avoiding streams makes for more readable code (and faster). However, in this case, I would go straight for the streams. If `flatMap` was involved, the choice would be much closer.

Comment: can you give the same answer in java 7 not including lambdas?

Comment: @HorseVoice: Added Java 7 version here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58871387/2015408

Comment: Or perform a `flatMap` to avoid `contains` over a list, `m.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).anyMatch(str -> str.equals("gummi"))`

Comment: @Naman You could, but I don't think there would be much advantage in this case. `flatMap` makes it less clear and, I think, the performance will be worse. It does, however, allow you to  switch the predicate to something more interesting.

Answer (score 4):

```
Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

    m.put("1", list1);
    m.put("2", list2);

    System.out.println(m.containsValue(list1));
    System.out.println(m.containsValue(list2));
    System.out.println(m.containsValue(list3));
```

**Output**

```
true
true
true
```

**Explanation**

As long as the new list is empty, **the hashcode value is always 1**. So list1,list2 and list3 will all have the hashcode value of 1. Basically meaning,

```
list1 = list2 = list3
```

So even if we check m.containsValue(list3); it will return **true**. But if the list is not empty, each list will have a unique hashcode. So as long as you have a map with non-empty lists then we could use containsValue(listObject) which will return correct result. Example below,

```
Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

    list1.add("apple");
    list1.add("orange");

    list2.add("mobile");
    list2.add("computer");

    m.put("1", list1);
    m.put("2", list2);

    System.out.println(m.containsValue(list1));
    System.out.println(m.containsValue(list2));
    System.out.println(m.containsValue(list3));
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
```

**Other use cases:**

If we want to check whether the value in the map is of type list or we would like to check a value is present in one of the list, then we can iterate the map as below,

```
for (String key : m.keySet()) {
        if (m.get(key) instanceof List) {
            for (String listItem : m.get(key)) {
                if ("valueWeSearchFor".equalsIgnoreCase(listItem)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }else{
            //If the value in the map is not of type list
            //What to do!!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've checked two scenarios using java 8. The below analysis is for the worst-case scenario.

**scenario 1: map contains 1000000 keys**

It seems to be in this scenario, java stream API is slower than loops. the map contains 1000000 keys. the Streams took 107543400 nanoseconds to complete the task. Loops took 73688600 nanoseconds. however, The parallel stream only took 51464500 nanoseconds.

checkout the below solution code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        App app = new App();
        String parameter = "invalid value";
        int numberOfKeys = 1000000;

        Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<>();

        // adding values to map
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfKeys ; i++) {
            m.put(i + "",
                    Arrays.asList(i * 10 + "", i * 11 + "", i * 12 + "", i * 13 + "", i * 14 + "", i * 15 + ""));
        }

        /** check time difference **/

        System.out.println("Loops");
        long begin = System.nanoTime();
        boolean b = app.containsValue_loops(m, parameter);
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - begin);
        System.out.println(b);

        System.out.println("\nJava 8 - stream");
        begin = System.nanoTime();
        boolean a = app.containsValue_java8(m, parameter);
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - begin);
        System.out.println(a);

        System.out.println("\nJava 8 - parallel stream");
        begin = System.nanoTime();
        boolean c = app.containsValue_java8_parallel(m, parameter);
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - begin);
        System.out.println(c);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}


/** Checks parameter contains in the list using loops **/
public boolean containsValue_loops(Map<String, List<String>> m, String parameter) {
    for (List<String> list : m.values()) {
        if (list.contains(parameter)) {
            // return immediately if value contains in the list
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/** Checks parameter contains in the list using streams **/
public boolean containsValue_java8(Map<String, List<String>> m, String parameter) {
    return m.values().stream().anyMatch(list -> list.contains(parameter));
}

/** Checks parameter contains in the list using parallel streams **/
public boolean containsValue_java8_parallel(Map<String, List<String>> m, String parameter) {
    return m.values().parallelStream().anyMatch(list -> list.contains(parameter));
}
```

This is the output :

```
Loops
73688600
false

Java 8 - stream
107543400
false

Java 8 - parallel stream
51464500
false
```

**scenario 2: map contains only 10 keys**

This is the output :

```
Loops
185000
false

Java 8 - stream
31721800
false

Java 8 - parallel stream
2987000
false
```

In this scenario, for loops take less time than streams. it is also faster than parallel streams.

So as the conclusion my suggestion is to use loops for a small collection, and use a parallel stream if you have a larger collection.

Answer (score 1):

### Java 7: `contains` for `Map<String, List<String>>`

Assuming the same as Tom, here is a Java 7 version (as requested by [Horse Voice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445444/horse-voice)):

```
// Live version
static boolean contains(Map<String, List<String>> map, String value) {
    for (List<String> list : map.values()) {
        if(list.contains(value)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If your source Map doesn't change, it *might* be better to create a search cache:

```
// Cached version
private List<String> allValues = getInnerValues(map);
private List<String> getInnerValues(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<String> list : map.values()) {
        result.addAll(list);
    }
    return result;
}

static boolean contains(String value) {
    return allValues.contains(value);
}
```

### Java 7: `anyKeyForValue` and `keysForValue`

I figure some people will want the key(s) that match the value:

```
// Live version
static String anyKeyForValue(Map<String, List<String>> map, String value) {
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue().contains(value)) return entry.getKey();
    }
    return null;
}

static List<String> keysForValue(Map<String, List<String>> map, String value) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue().contains(value)) result.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Caching is a little harder; we need to invert the Map:

```
// Cached version
private Map<String, List<String>> valueKeys = invert(map);
private Map<String, List<String>> invert(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
    Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        for (value : entry.getValue()) {
            List<String> keys;
            if (result.containsKey(value)) {
                keys = result.get(value);
            } else {
                keys = new ArrayList<String>();
                result.put(value, keys);
            }
            keys.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

static List<String> keysForValue(String value) {
    return valueKeys.get(value);
}
```

Comment: i think this code is right answer, have you tried this code @max

Answer (score 1):

Iterate Map collection to check inputString with every map values so that you can use match found keys for further use.

```
    Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<>();
    String searchStr="a";
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("a");
    list1.add("b");
    m.put("1", list1);
    list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("c");
    m.put("2", list1);
    list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("a");
    list1.add("d");
    m.put("3", list1);

    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : m.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().contains(searchStr)) {
            System.out.println(searchStr+" found for map key="+entry.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tom's answer is the best however, @HorseVoice asked for Java 7 version, which is as below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925049/check-if-a-list-is-a-value-in-a-hashmap
 *
 * @author surender.kumar
 */
public class CheckListValueInHashMapExists {

    public static final Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running main ...");
        initM();
        String gummi = "gummi";

        System.out.println("Do the list contains value gummi? " + checkValueExistsJava7());
    }

    private static boolean checkValueExistsJava7() {
        for (List<String> list : m.values()) {
            if (list.contains("gummi")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void initM() {
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("value1a");
        list1.add("value1b");
        list2.add("value2");
        list2.add("gummi");
        m.put("1", list1);
        m.put("2", list2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Running main ...
Do the list contains value gummi? true
```

Comment: If you're not going to cache, then you should definitely be short-circuiting when you find a match! You might find "gummi" in the first list!

Answer (score 0):

I think Surender Kherwa' answer qualifies, but I think when you look for an element in a collection it's better to use `while` loop instead of `for`, here's the example (for java 7) :

```java
String gummi = "gummi";
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>() {
{

put("KEY1", new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("check");
    add("if");
    add("a");
    add("list");
    add("is");
}});

put("KEY2", new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("a");
    add("gummi");
    add("value");
    add("in");
    add("a");
}});

put("KEY3", new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("HashMap");
    add("java");
    add("7");
    add("while");
    add("loop");
    add("version");
}});

}};

Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry = iterator.next();
  if (entry.getValue().contains(gummi)) {
    System.out.println("Found in : " + entry.getKey());
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think the `while` loop is better. Not unless you were going for some kind of SESE (Single Entry Single Exit) style: `while (iterator.hasNext() && (entry = iterator.next()).getValue().equals(gummi)) {`. (Not a style I particularly like, but see where it is coming from, but not particularly helpful here.)

Comment: In addition to previous comment. Don't use double-bracket initialization, we don`t need useless anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is a list, the contains method of the List can be used to check if the 
List has the required String.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    public static final Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<>();
    checkStringInMapOfLists("gummi",m);
}
```

The below method iterates over the values in the hashmap and checks if any of the lists in the hashmap contains the required String

```
private boolean checkStringInMapOfLists(String input,Map<String, List<String>> m){
    for(List<String> list : m.values()){
        if(list.contains(input))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself how much resources you want to waste and what is the runtime you can allow for this task. So assuming that you want a straight-forward solution, the solution becomes very simple. Since you are using a hash-map, the keys are not sorted by anything, so you can just iterate the keys and see whether the list contains the value is true and break the loop if it does. Since this solution is too simple and sounds like a homework, I will leave the solution to you. It is just a few lines of a code. From a top of my head, it would look like:

```
for(String key:m.keyset()){
if(m.get(key).contains("gummi")) return true;
}
return false;
```

Furthermore, if there is any connection between the key and the list context, there are numerous ways of finding a solution. One is using the A.I. and regression/training so you can guess the content of the list without looking at it.

Another solution would be a map-reduce for multi-core and parallel processing.

See, your question is awesome, and different people with different backgrounds can answer it differently. The problem is, you haven't defined the parameters such as desired performance, the amount of data you would be processing, etc. so anything that works is the right answer.

Furthermore, in the world of pointers, you could design your own data structure to solve this with the best performance. Otherwise, you could use trees, and other acrobatics... but you have to describe the frame of the problem.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frame-problem/

also you can have a o(n) while simply reading the object as a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for an existence of an object within any of the values of the `Map`. Using an approach involving `Stream` from Java-8 and above, you can make use of `flatMap` and collect `toSet` performing an efficient `contains` on the flattened collection:

```
boolean presentInAnyValue = m.values().stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        .contains("gummi");
```

A Java-7 transformation of this code would look like:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
for (List<String> strings : m.values()) {
    set.addAll(strings);
}
boolean presentInAnyValue = set.contains("gummi");
```

Comment: ... and the reason to downvote is? (just a comment for the downvoter, not that I actually expect a reply :))

Answer (score 0):

This will get the key for any value contained within a list within a map. Java 7

```
public String getKeyForValue(String value) {
    for (String key : map.keySet())
        if (map.get(key).contains(value))
            return key;
    return null;
}
```

This will return true or false if the value is contained anywhere within a list within the hash map, Java 7.

```
public boolean mapContains(String value) {
    for (String key : map.keySet())
        if (map.get(key).contains(value))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did just change the object types to whatever you need

```
private static boolean isInListOfHash(Map<List<String>, ICommand> hashMap, String word) {
    for (List<String> list : hashMap.keySet()) {
        for (String string : list)
            if (string.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Quoting from the [`List.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) Javadoc:

> In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.

Therefore, to check if a value exist, you can create a list and call [`containsValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue-java.lang.Object-) with that `List`, because this method will call `equals` to determine equality. If the same elements are in the same order, a match will be found.

You can easily create a `List` from an array of values with [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

```
if(m.containsValue(Arrays.asList("gummi"))) {...}
```

Sample code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> m = new HashMap<>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("1");
list.add("2");
m.put("key", list);

if (m.containsValue(Arrays.asList("1", "2"))) {
    System.out.println("contains value");
}
```

Comment: This requires the caller to know all members of the list that is a value.

Comment: @Tunaki, this is not what the questioner is asking.. If you already knew the contents of the array then this problem is trivial. Interesting problem to solve if you don't know what the contents of the list will contain. Your answer takes a shortcut and doesn't fully answer the question. I've set a bounty on this.

Answer (score -1):

hashMap is key value stores and is slow when you want to search value in to values so firstly normalize your map to like this swap to key and values

```
Map<String, String> searchMap = m.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(etn -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(etn, entry.getKey())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

and after search value like this

```
String mkey = searchMap.get("gummi");
```

now mkey is orijinal map keys. if is null not exist in any values in orijinal map and you access founded list like this if key not null

```
List<String> mValue = m.get(mkey);
```

Comment: Um, I'm sure it works. It's only appropriate for situations where you are going to do many searches without updating the underlying data, which seems niche. If you want that mapping, probably keep it that way. Having said that, maintaining multiple copies of data in the presence of errors is troublesome. / In general the reverse mapping of `Map<K, List<V>>` will be `Map<V, Collection<K>>` not `Map<V, K>`. `Collectors.groupingBy` may or may not be useful Also, there is `Map.entry` from ye olde, not publicly maintained by Oracle, Java SE 9. (Not my -1, btw.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline thanks to comment. I just though search and your comments absolutely true